# How to set location of an header to a secure php file?(file that is not in public folder)

Tags: php, hosting

I am hosting a website using godaddy and have all my files stored in **public_html** folder. One of these files say *update.php* is called at the end of another php file using

```
header('location: update.php').
```

I do not want this update.php file to be accessed directly.
I am having a payment gateway between these two php files so I cannot set test variables as they will get set even if the payment gateway process fails which needs to be avoided.

Can this problem be solved if I place the update.php file in some other folder? If so then how can i set the header location to it? Note:

```
header('location: ../xyz/update.php')
```

and

```
$secure_dir=dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."secure".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
include($secure_dir."update.php");
```

these methods do not seem to work.

Again I am using godaddy hosting so anyone familiar with this problem please suggest a solution.

Comment: By using server redirection you need to make the file directly accessable. If you don't want that, you need to include that file in a file which can be accessed directly.

Comment: I want it to run only after the payment gateway is successful.

Comment: Then include that file when you get the payment confirmation.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can store it in another folder and then use header to that location? I have read that storing files one level higher is best way but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: If that location is directly accessable for anyone, sure. But since you don't want that, redirection is no option. You **need** to include that file on the server.

Comment: Ok thanx for the suggestion.